# Kendu Grid - Function inside row template always undefined

Tags: css, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to use a custom row template on my grid so i can give various class declarations to individual cells in the grid.

The function i am trying to call to return the string for the css class is always undefined, no matter where i declare it.

This is the code for my grid declaration file:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

var logPrefix = 'sampleRequestTrackingGrid --> ';
var rowTemplateString =
    '<tr data-uid="#= uid #">' +
    '<td>#: requestedBy #</td>' +
    '<td>#: site #</td>' +
    '<td>#: sampleLot#</td>' +
    '<td>#: sampleProcess #</td>' +
    '<td>#: workOrderId #</td>' +
    '<td>#: equipmentId #</td>' +
    '<td>#: area #</td>' +
    '<td>#: cell #</td>' +
    '<td>#: station #</td>' +
    '<td>#: testMethods #</td>' +
    '<td>#: requestedDate #</td>' +
    '<td class="#: getStatus(requestStatus) #">#: requestStatus #</td>' +
    '<td>#: requestStatusMsg #</td>' +
    '<td>#: requestId #</td>' +
    '</tr';

function getStatus(requestStatus){
    if(requestStatus === 'In Queue'){
        return 'inQueue';
    }
    else if(requestStatus === 'In Progress'){
        return 'inProgress';
    }
    else if(requestStatus === 'Complete'){
        return 'complete';
    }
    else if(requestStatus === 'Failed'){
        return 'failed';
    }
}

angular.module('wm.sampleRequestTracking')
    .constant('SampleRequestTrackingGrid', {
        options: function(model){
            return {
                dataBound: model.onGridDataBound,
                dataSource: {
                    data: model.gridData,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "requestSysI",
                            fields: {
                                requestSysI: {editable: false},
                                requestedBy: {editable: false},
                                site: {editable: false},
                                sampleLot: {editable: false},
                                sampleProcess: {editable: false},
                                workOrderId: {editable: false},
                                equipmentId: {editable: false},
                                area: {editable: false},
                                cell: {editable: false},
                                station: {editable: false},
                                testMethods: {editable: false},
                                requestedDate: {editable: false, type: "datetime"},
                                requestStatus: {editable: false},
                                requestStatusMsg: {editable: false},
                                requestId: {editable: false}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 200
                },
                scrollable: true,
                resizable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                pageable: true,
                groupable:true,
                filterable: true,
                autobind: false,
                columnMenu: true,
                navigatable: true,
                selectable: true,
                sortable: {mode: "multiple"},
                columns: [
                    {field: "requestedBy", title: "Requested By", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "site", title: "Site", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "sampleLot", title: "Lot", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "sampleProcess", title: "Process", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "workOrderId", title: "Work Order", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "equipmentId", title: "Equipment", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "area", title: "Request Area", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "cell", title: "Request Cell", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "station", title: "Request Station", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "testMethods", title: "Test Methods", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "requestedDate", title: "Request Date", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "requestStatus", title: "Request Status", width: "100px", template: "<span id='reqStatus'>#=requestStatus#</span>"},
                    {field: "requestId", title: "Request Id", width: "100px", hidden: false}
                ],
                rowTemplate: rowTemplateString
            };
        }
    });
})();
```

Assuming everything was working correctly, I would change the background color of the classes using the following CSS inside a .less file

```
.inQueue {
    background-color: white;
}

.inProgress {
    background-color: #fda;
}

.complete {
    background-color: #ced;
}

.failed {
    background-color: #fdd;
}
```

But, every time i run the code and try to load the grid i get an error telling me that `getStatus()` function is not defined.

Can anyone offer some assistance in figuring out what i am doing wrong here?

For reference: the Telerik article i was following is 
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/style-rows-cells-based-on-data-item-values

Comment: Not sure if this is hurting you, but your closing tr tag is missing a >

Comment: I fixed that, thanks. But that was not the issue. I have tried adding it to the global scope inside my controller by placingit there and using `$scope.getStatus = getStatus;` but that didnt help either

Comment: Did you try putting `getStatus` function outside the IIFE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using a row template, as i realized it was a little unnecessary and too complex for what i needed, and instead modified my field template.

Also, as @Soham commented, placing the `getStatus` function outside the IIFE did work. I had done that previously, but perhaps it was because of my typo on the `tr` that it failed before.

```
(function(){
'use strict';

var logPrefix = 'sampleRequestTrackingGrid --> ';

angular.module('wm.sampleRequestTracking')
    .constant('SampleRequestTrackingGrid', {
        options: function(model){
            return {
                dataBound: model.onGridDataBound,
                dataSource: {
                    data: model.gridData,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "requestSysI",
                            fields: {
                                requestSysI: {editable: false},
                                requestedBy: {editable: false},
                                batteryId: {editable: false},
                                site: {editable: false},
                                sampleLot: {editable: false},
                                sampleProcess: {editable: false},
                                workOrderId: {editable: false},
                                equipmentId: {editable: false},
                                area: {editable: false},
                                cell: {editable: false},
                                station: {editable: false},
                                testMethods: {editable: false},
                                requestedDate: {editable: false, type: "datetime"},
                                requestStatus: {editable: false},
                                requestStatusMsg: {editable: false},
                                requestId: {editable: false}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 200
                },
                scrollable: true,
                resizable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                pageable: true,
                groupable:true,
                filterable: true,
                autobind: false,
                columnMenu: true,
                navigatable: true,
                selectable: true,
                sortable: {mode: "multiple"},
                columns: [
                    {field: "requestedBy", title: "Requested By", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "batteryId", title: "Battery", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "site", title: "Site", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "sampleLot", title: "Lot", width: "150px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "sampleProcess", title: "Process", width: "150px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "workOrderId", title: "Work Order", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "equipmentId", title: "Equipment", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "area", title: "Request Area", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "cell", title: "Request Cell", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "station", title: "Request Station", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "testMethods", title: "Test Methods", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "requestedDate", title: "Request Date", width: "100px", hidden: false},
                    {field: "requestStatus", title: "Request Status", width: "100px", template: "<div class='#=getStatus(requestStatus)#' id='reqStatus' style='text-align: center'>#=requestStatus#</div>"},
                    {field: "requestId", title: "Request Id", width: "100px", hidden: false}
                ]
            };
        }
    });

})();

function getStatus(requestStatus){
    if(requestStatus === 'In Queue'){
        return 'inQueue';
    }
    else if(requestStatus === 'In Progress'){
        return 'inProgress';
    }
    else if(requestStatus === 'Complete'){
        return 'complete';
    }
    else if(requestStatus === 'Failed'){
        return 'failed';
    }
}
```

With the end result being:
[screenshot of column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcvML.png)